# import to excel a text file using cell value

Tags: import, excel, vba

I have some .txt output files that I would like to import in excel.

Ideally I want to use Sheet1 as an index; where I will write a title, the name of the sheet and the path and name for the .txt file. The Macro should create a newSheet named as the cell and in that sheet import the corresponding .txt file.

I been trying to record a macros and to changing the VBA code, but so far just failures.

```
With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
"TEXT;C:\Documents and Settings\UserXP\My Documents\My Dropbox\CIPPEC\1-MIRA\Procesamiento base\OEDE\Tablas\trim\q_employ_pcia_23.txt" _
, Destination:=Range("$A$1")).Name = "q_employ_pcia_23"
```

Any idea?

Thanks

Comment: How does your data look in `Sheet1`?

Answer (score 0):

```
With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
"TEXT;C:\Documents and Settings\UserXP\My Documents\My Dropbox\CIPPEC\1-MIRA\Procesamiento base\OEDE\Tablas\trim\q_employ_pcia_23.txt" _
, Destination:=Range("$A$1"))
.Name = "q_employ_pcia_23"
.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
End With
ActiveSheet.Name = "q_employ_pcia_23"
```

works to get the import into a new sheet and you want to name the new sheet also.